# Blender doesn't startup

Tags: error

I use Linux Mint 18.3, I updated my system, then, when I startup Blender it crashed. This is the error:

```
# Blender 2.79 (sub 0), Unknown revision

# backtrace
/usr/lib/blender/blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x30) [0x17914d0]
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0xd2b9d1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0) [0x7f2a3cad74b0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x5e2eb6) [0x7f2a0f6f5eb6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x5e4559) [0x7f2a0f6f7559]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x5d1468) [0x7f2a0f6e4468]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x5d2345) [0x7f2a0f6e5345]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x3f34da) [0x7f2a0f5064da]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x3f3ddd) [0x7f2a0f506ddd]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x42a333) [0x7f2a0f53d333]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x17812e) [0x7f2a0f28b12e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so(+0x17dda3) [0x7f2a0f290da3]
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0xd2f76d]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(wm_draw_update+0x882) [0xd312b2]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(WM_main+0x28) [0xd2c678]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(main+0x376) [0xce5b96]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f2a3cac2830]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(_start+0x29) [0xd28689]
```

Can someone help me? Please.

Comment: Maybe reinstalling the program could help?

Comment: this may sound naive but, what's your GPU?, sorry for posting this as a Answer but i can't comment yet (need more reputation). It seems to be a problem with your GPU driver. So you can try reinstalling that driver. Hope this can point you the right way.

Comment: does glxgears run? If not you will need to install compatible graphics drivers

Comment: I've got a similar issue with Ubuntu 20.04; blender 3.0.1 from snap (also 2.8.2 from apt) crashes when I start it. my GPU is a Radeon R5 M330 (yes, it's old). Not sure which drivers to install.